# No OpsCenter in Cassandra installation in Windows

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

I downloaded the last version of Cassandra (v3.3.0) from here:
http://www.planetcassandra.org/cassandra/
I ran some `cql` commands and it works great.
However in the installation process I hadn't seen the OpsCenter (no opportunity to tag it). I tried to find it in the Windows services - it is not there and I tried to go directly to the port: `http://localhost:8888/opscenter/index.html` and it doesn't exist. I opened the programs and it is not there as well. How can I add/ install Cassandra OpsCenter?
[image]
[image]
It is clearly written here:

```
http://www.planetcassandra.org/cassandra/
```

DataStax DevCenter (Included in the Windows .MSI installer packages; click here to download & setup DevCenter for other operating systems)
However, when installed no Centos option offered and no sign for services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting opscenter because you have downloaded the latest version of cassandra which does not support opscenter.Versions previous to 3.0 support opscenter.As you can see versions 2.1-3.0 are marked legacy.

[image: version]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a way to use opscenter for the latest version?

Comment: No,not that I know of.But DataStax is now giving DevCenter with new versions.Use commandline,its always best and gives you the feel of the process.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to go to Datastax and download the OpsCenter and install it. OpsCenter will need datastax-agent installed also. You can read more [HERE](http://www.datastax.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/WP-DataStax-OpsCenter.pdf?2)

I am not sure of the Cassandra releases supported by OpsCenter, but give it a shot. You can download OpsCenter [HERE](http://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-enterprise-visual-admin) , just make sure you have a Datastax-agent running and configured in address.yaml

Comment: Thanks. As far as I understand the Cassandra installation should include OpsCenter as well (see: http://www.luketillman.com/developing-with-cassandra-on-windows/) and my case (a newer version) it didn't. I would like to know if someone had such a case and direct instructions for windows installation.

Comment: Important to note, but future versions of OpsCenter (6.x+) will not support the community (non-enterprise) versions of Cassandra.  Also OpsCenter 5.2 reduces some functionality when you add a non-enterprise cluster to it.

Comment: I am running both Apache Cassandra as well as the DSE releases and I have always had to download it separately. Like I said tho I am not sure what release Cassandra OpsCenter will support

Comment: Could you please instruct me what should I do? Where to download from? How to install?

Comment: I edited my answer. Please read the installation instructions, there are a couple ways to install it depending on your host machine and OS, which you don't specify in your post

Comment: Thanks, isn't there a way to freely download with no need to register?

Comment: registration is free

Comment: I found something here but not for windows: http://www.planetcassandra.org/opscenter/. Could you find download with no need to register?

Comment: If you pay me I will do the work for you, otherwise you need to figure out how to download opscenter without registering. BTW, you could have registered, downloaded and installed it by now and not posted the last 3 comments

Comment: I registered and there are 2 options for download: for mac and linux only. I am looking for version for Windows.

Comment: google opscenter on windows and go to the first hit.. looks like it comes with DSE and not the planet cassandra release. You'll need to figure out the windows side, i don't use windows for anything but email. If you're serious about OpenSource you will move off windows and into Linux/Unix

Comment: Already been at the first link. It returns me back to Cassandra installation page. Is there anyone who installed it on Windows?